# android.view.InflateException when calling facebook.authorize

Tags: android, facebook, exception, inflate-exception

---

**EDIT 1/14/2013** - I tried redownloading the facebook SDK... Still the same error.

---

I am getting android.view.InflateException caused by outOfMemoryException when calling facebook.authorize together with the looper.

**This is a snippet of my code where the calling of facebook.authorize is being done:**

```
public void promptLogin(){
    if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginAndContinue();
    }
    else {
        Continue();
    }
}
public void loginAndContinue(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Looper.prepare();
            openLoginDialog();
            Looper.loop(); // This is line 248
        }
    }).start();
}
public void openLoginDialog(){
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
}
public void Continue(){
    AsyncFacebookRunner myAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    myAsyncRunner.request("me", new meRequestListener(this));
}
```

**And here is the log error:**

```
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-105
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #107: Error
> inflating class <unknown>
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:240)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:198)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:353)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:257)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$DialogWebViewClient.onPageStarted(WebDialog.java:364)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:267)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at com.COMPANYNAME.framework.impl.AndroidGame$6.run(AndroidGame.java:248)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    ... 20 more
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
>     01-14 19:42:04.551: E/AndroidRuntime(890):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
```

It worked like a charm before, but now, after adding a button (programmatically), it doesn't work anymore.

**Just if it helps you to help me, here is the code where I inflate a linearlayout where I store the facebook picture and textview for the name:**

**JAVA:**

```
    setContentView(gameLayout);
    View.inflate(this, R.layout.facebook, gameLayout);
    facebookLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.facebookLayout);
    facebookName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.facebookName);
    profilePicture = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
    profilePicture.setCropped(true);
    getNameAndId();
    facebookName.setText("Welcome, " + name + "!");
    showFacebook(false);
    checkState();
}

public void checkState() {
    if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebookName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        profilePicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/facebookLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        facebook:preset_size="small" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/facebookName"
        android:text="Welcome!"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope you can help me, because I have no clue on how to proceed from here.

Comment: This line `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)` implies you are loading an image from your drawable resources.  Did you modify any other layout files to include a large background image or something of that nature?

Comment: That's wierd, because I am not loading anything from my drawable resources. All of the images are stored in assets and loaded from there at startup. Except for the facebook library in which the images are loaded from drawables... Oh and by the way, the only layout file that I've got is the xml file that I put up in the question.

Comment: must be facebook, then.  Though, why are you running `authorize` on a background thread?  If it touches the UI it should be on the main thread.

Comment: I've tried that. But the problem is that the thread freezes when the dialog is closed.

Comment: What do yo mean freeze?  It should invoke one of the callbacks in your `LoginDialogListener`, are you getting that response?

Comment: Yes. The response is fine but I can't interact with the game after that. Like it's frozen. Anyhow, I tried replacing the loginAndContinue() call with Looper.prepare();
            openLoginDialog();
            Looper.loop(); but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: I am not sure how `Looper` would help.  It might be in your callback routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working now! It seemed like I had too many images loaded into memory at the same time. I tried commenting out some of the big images and voila! It worked!

The solution is that you'll have to recycle the images when switching between screens where they are not needed. That way you'll save up lots of memory and not have to face the same problem as I did.

**Do this when you do not need an image anymore:**

```
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
```